# How to stop/cancel a Chutzpah test run that has been started with "Run JS Tests" and takes too long?

Tags: javascript, testing, visual-studio-2015, chutzpah

I use Chutzpah 4.3.3 in Visual Studio Community 2015 and I am able to run all my tests (about 500) with right click on a folder and choosing "Run JS Tests" from the context menu. While the tests are running some test files are highlighted in the solution explorer with red squiggled lines to denote that the corresponding test failed.

At that point I would like to stop/cancel the test run and inspect one of the failing tests in more detail. However, before I am able to debug the single test in the browser, I have to wait until Chutzpah is finished with my"run all tests" job.

I tried to kill the phantom.js process but that did not help.

=>How can I tell Chutzpah to cancel the tests? Or maybe there is a general VisualStudio feature that would allow me to cancel the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chutzpah currently does not support this. 
Also see this feature ticket:

https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/601